# tables automatically added to database when creating custom user model in django

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, django-rest-framework

I created a custom user model extending AbstractUser. But when making migrations, many tables were added to PostgreSQL, I have only two models.
I named my customuser : CustomUser and the other model Offers.
These tables were found in postgresql database:

`api_customuser api_customuser_groups api_customuser_user_permissions api_offers, auth_group, auth_group_permissions, auth_permission, django_admin.log`

and others
Note that my django app is named : api.
Is it normal?

Comment: Yes, this is normal. These tables are a part of Django's authentication and authorization feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is normal. These tables are a part of Django's authentication and authorization feature.